# Google Hangout Chat - Send Direct Message to user

Tags: php, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I am using various parts of GSuite - authenticating, accessing calendar and drive. I would like to offer users to be able to send direct messages to other users.

I cannot find any example of this online. I have found references to bots sending messages to rooms, but I want to send a message from the authenticated user, to another user in the gSuite.

Could anybody please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hello @StripyTiger, would you mind providing more information about what exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to be able to send direct messages to a user by impersonating another user? Or do you want the messages to be on your behalf? Cheers!

Comment: Hi @ale13 - ideally from myself (whoever is logged in). This is on an intranet so all users are authenticated with GSuite in order to access calendar and drive.  I would like to be able to send a message directly from the intranet to another user. Thanks

Comment: Hello @StripyTiger, why isn't Hangouts Chat a viable option then? Have you tried it? Cheers!

Comment: Hello @ale13 . We do use Hangouts Chat, but I want to be able to quickly send a message directly from the intranet. So, if a user is mentioned in a post on the intranet, I want to convert the name into a link, that when pressed will be able just open a window, and a message can be typed and sent without leaving the intranet.

Comment: Hi @StripyTiger: Hangouts or Google Chat, where do you want to send message exactly? If it is Google Chat - then there are some pre-requisites.

Comment: Hi @DarpanSanghavi - it is a Hangouts Chat direct message I want to send - they seem to be combined now. https://zapier.com/blog/google-hangouts-meet-guide/#hangoutschat

Comment: Okay, Google has officially dropped the word 'Hangouts' - so now Google Chat only supports direct message from a BOT to a person via API. It is not possible to send a message using API on a person's behalf. If this is useful - I will add a detailed answer on the possible part.

Comment: Thank you . This would be very useful - thank you

Comment: In this situation, in order for Google Chat to be able to interact with your users, just like @DarpanSanghavi mentioned, a bot would be the best option. You might want to take a look at this link [here](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/connect-web-apps). Does this provide any help to you?